# Unable to access GRUB menu for password reset in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, password, password-recovery

I am facing difficulty in resetting a lost admin password for Ubuntu 20.04.3
According to various [online resources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password), the recommended method is to access the GRUB menu, enter recovery mode, and reset the password from there. However, when I press Esc during the boot-up process, instead of displaying the GRUB menu, a series of commands start running and eventually I end up on the home screen.

Is there an alternative method or a workaround to access the GRUB menu in this situation? I really need to reset the admin password, and any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[After pressing Esc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Okk.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: 20.04.3 LTS desktop

Comment: Correct your question then, 20 is a *flavor* & Server only system.  Also note:  A fully upgraded 20.04 system will report as 20.04.6, so if yours reported as 20.04.3, either you've not been applying security fixes, or you're not using Ubuntu but a Ubuntu based system or made other errors.

Comment: @guiverc I've updated the question. In my case, the system is indeed Ubuntu 20.04.3, and I understand the importance of keeping the system up-to-date with security fixes. I'll do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/1695860, is asking to edit the admin files which will ask for password before editing. Also won't be able to run `sudo update-grub`